# Subreport isn't matching mainreport [Design]

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Hello I was trying to add a subreport to my SSRS report inside the same `Tablix`

[image]

it starts the `subreport` at quote# see how it doesn't look like it belongs to that table? How can I fix that?

here is the design:

[image]

Comment: What issue faced when previewing. Let me know clearly.

Comment: @SoundappanA the top picture is it previewing, doesn't have the line under the column names